# Crystal Report No Header for SubReport

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-xi

Can someone PLEASE give me a clear instruction on how to supress the header (from the main report) on the Sub Report? I would greatly appreciate it! I am using Crystal Report 9. I only need to know how to supress the header on Subreport which is comming from the Main Report. I need the header to stay on the main report but I just dont want it to be there in the subreport when it shows up.

Comment: when will the sub report will be displayed in main report?

Comment: Subreportbis kn the details section  on main reports

Comment: Report Header or Page Header? I don't see how a header from the main report would be carried into a subreport. Can you screenshot the behavior?